# double precision numbers into an array, then sort and display number from lowest to highest

Tags: java, sorting, double-precision

In line 24, I am getting an error which is commented out. What is causing this and how to I get it fixed?

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks ahead of time. :)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class main {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        //initialize array
        double[] numbers = new double [10];

        //Create Scanner object
        System.out.print("Enter " + numbers.length + " values: ");

        //initialize array
        for ( int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
            numbers[i] = input.nextDouble() ;
            java.util.Arrays.sort(numbers[i]); //getting an error here, thay says [The method sort(int[]) in the type Arrays is not applicable for the arguments (double)]
        //Display array numbers
        System.out.print(" " + numbers);            
        }

        //Close input
        input.close();

    }


}
```

Comment: Get the sort call outside the loop, and apply it to numbers, not to a single element of numbers. Sorting is an array operation, not an operation on an array element.

Comment: @Patricia Thanks for the quick reply, I am getting  [D@1042bb13 for number values

Comment: //initialize array
  double[] numbers = new double [10];
  java.util.Arrays.sort(numbers);

Comment: sort **after** you have added the elements. Printing just numbers is not going to be very interesting. Try iterating over its elements before and after the sort: `for(double d : numbers)System.out.println(d);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to sort the complete array rather than a single element:

```
Arrays.sort(numbers);
```

Better to move it outside of the `for`-loop. You could use `Arrays.toString` to display the contents of the array itself:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
   numbers[i] = input.nextDouble();
}
Arrays.sort(numbers);
System.out.print(Arrays.toString(numbers));
```

---

Note: Class names start with an uppercase letter, e.g. `MyMain`.

Answer (score 3):

Put this **after** the for loop:

```
java.util.Arrays.sort(numbers);
```

notice **numbers** not numbers[i] **and** the print needs to come out of that loop too.

Answer (score 1):

The mistake you're making is that you are trying to sort a single number. The error message points out that the sort method expects an array.

Your algorithm should first read in all the numbers, before sorting. So change your code to something like this:

```
...

// first read in numbers
for ( int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
    numbers[i] = input.nextDouble() ;
}

// then apply sort
java.util.Arrays.sort(numbers); // numbers is an array, so it's a valid argument.

// finally, after sorting you may now output the sorted array
for(int number : numbers){
    System.out.println(number);
}

...
```

Comment: Thank you. I am new to programming but like the challenge. Made the changes and get [D@1042bb13 instead of numbers

Comment: it's ok Vic, we were all once there. Sorry, printing the sorted array should be System.out.println(number);

Comment: the mistake I made earlier in my answer is printing 'numbers' instead of 'number'. In case you are wondering what 'D@1042bb13' means, it's a reference to the 'numbers' array object in memory. Any way, I've corrected my answer, and it should work now. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you, will put this in.

Comment: I thought you chose my answer, so why did you refuse it later on? :-)

Comment: I am new to this, forgive me.